# Android - Permanently hide navigation bar

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

I need to hide the navigation bar on a tablet with 4.0 completely. No user interaction should change this behavior. Right now I'm running the default Fullscreen View from Android Studio, but user interaction brings up the navigation bar.
Is there a way to do that without root?

Comment: You can't do this, and for very good reason: A malicious app could trap the user inside of the app indefinitely. If your app design requires such a feature, then you need to reconsider your app design.

Comment: @Karakuri is there any way to get Navigation bar is hidden or not? As Android P comes in Navigation Gesture.

Answer (score 1):

Unless phone is rooted - you cannot override the standard behavior or Android OS. 
In fullscreen mode i will be hidden, but can be still brought down when required.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the app like a Launcher, hide the navigation bar, and root the phone, in order to set always run that.

The other option is root the phone, and make your own android version without the navigation bar.